# what can i do about these errors?

Tags: android, eclipse, button

```
package com.duncan.hello.world;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.duncan.hello.world.R;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button aButton;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HelloWorld.this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }});
}
}
```

I only have one error now, because I imported the button. The error is on line 23 and says "HelloWorld cannot be resolved to  a type"

Comment: You could import the classes you use, for starters :)

Comment: -1 for a not constructive question.

Comment: this is from a tutorial that i got from my last question, so don't yell at me.

Comment: in eclipse do control+shift+o to auto import (may not find all libraries, but all the android ones it should fine)

Comment: If you use eclipse, then eclipse will suggest corrections for nearly all errors you mentioned. 13 & 16: import Button class, 19: import View, 20: import Intent, change HelloWorld.this to HelloWorldActivity.this

Comment: if you are using eclipse, cmd+shift+o (ctrl+shift+o) includes the import for you.

Comment: verify that the path to the SDK Android on your Eclipse is supplied : to do : Window => Preferences => Android and verify the path of the android sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the classes you are using. Button cannot be resolved as a type because you haven't imported it yet.

It should have given you an error before you could even run the code with such a mistake.

Comment: i didn't even try to run the code because i can't run the code with errors, anyways you're saying to add something like import android.view.button?

Comment: Have you even added the Android SDK to your IDE yet? If you using eclipse Android has a plug in here..  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Comment: Sounds like you are missing one of the requirements.

Comment: yes, i am using eclipse.

Comment: yes, i do have the SDK plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Soo, you need to import the class for Button.

Comment: usually in eclipse if you hove over the Button code it will give you an option to import it.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity name is `HelloWorldActivity`, but you have used `HelloWorld` in the Intent.
Replace this code,

```
Intent i = new Intent(HelloWorld.this, OtherActivity.class);
```

Replace above by following code,

```
Intent i = new Intent(HelloWorldActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
```